# Retrieve variable value and not name of this variable

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to add a value to a json structure like :

```
saveChamp.test = {"type":"","text":""};
```

It's ok, but i want "test" like : `var test = $('blablabla').val();`

In my example, it does not fetch the value of test but it creates an entry with the name test. This is not what I want.

Help ?

Edit :

```
var saveChamp = new Object();
var test = "Field1";
saveChamp.test = {"type":"ok","text":"kok"};
```

I want that script create an entry in saveChamp with the name Field1 (value of ma variable test).

Comment: *"json structure"* That's not JSON, that's just an object. JSON is just a textual notation used for data interchange. If you're writing **code**, you're writing object initializers which, when run, create objects in memory.

Comment: My example create an entry with THE NAME "TEST", not the value of my variable "test".

Comment: @ClémentAndraud: Your example does neither of those things. Please try to put what you want to do very simply. (Get help from colleagues if English is a barrier.)

Comment: I have edit...Do you understand ??

Comment: Thank you for the edit, it's clear what you need now, check my second answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, in this case, after your edit it's obvious what you need.

every object in javascript can be treated as an associative array, and it is possible to call properties of an array by a variable's value..

```
var saveChamp = new Object();
var test = "Field1";
saveChamp[test] = {"type":"ok","text":"kok"};
```

this is the same as:

```
saveChamp["Field1"] = {"type":"ok","text":"kok"};
```

this will do what you want, as the name of the field is passed as a variable string.

Comment: I've already tested it and it creates me an entry with no name.

Comment: Your 2nd example works fine (saveChamp["Field1"]), but not the first ;)

Comment: let me look into that. one second.

Comment: did you copy paste this into a blank script and it didn't work? because this actually works.

Comment: Ok i know, when i test with : var test = $('#champ').val();, even if $('#champ').val() contains something, it create an empty name.....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand you fully, as this code doesn't make much sense.

JSON means [Javascript Object Notation](http://www.json.org/js.html).

It is used to transfer variables through plain text. you do not need this, as you can transfer you data via code.

ex. 1:

```
saveChamp.test = $('blablabla')).val();
```

will make the object saveChamp, have a property test, which has a value: $('blablabla')).val();

ex. 2:

```
saveChamp.test = {"type":"blablabla","text":$('blablabla')).val()};
```

will hopefully create an object, out of saveChamp's test property.
this actually means this:

```
saveChamp.test.type = "blabalbla"; 
saveChamp.test.text = $('blablabla')).val();
```

**EDIT**

i made a new answer, but leaving this one here, as they are both very different, and both useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the bracket notation:

```
var test = $('blablabla').val();
saveChamp[test] = {
    "type": "",
    "text": ""
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I see how you are trying to set your value and set is to a JSON object but if that is the exact code you are using it is missing the "#" to grab the element by Id and there is an extra paren;

Trey using:

```
var test = $('#blablabla').val(); 

saveChamp.test = {"type": "blablabla","text": test};
```